# How to open a PDF automatically using itext in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a Windows Form App which automatically generates a PDF using itext. I was using the following code previously to generate the PDF:

```
namespace ConsoleApp2 {class Program{static void Main(string[] args){
    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("C:/Users/bra/800C.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();

    document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);                             

    Paragraph p17 = new Paragraph("Use formulations of Penzien (2000) assuming full slip condition. ");
    document.Add(p17);

    document.Close();

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Is there a way that my code could be modified so that the PDF can be opened automatically when the program is run? (Rather than being saved on the C drive)? I have seen some examples with memoryStream online but couldn't wrap my head around how this works.

Comment: Do you have a PDF viewer control ? if yes some can take a stream as a source. If not you need to save the file and use a `Process.Start` to open the file with the computer default application

Comment: Hi Franck, I don't no. The purpose of the program is that other users can download it and open more complex PDFs on their computers. Originally I wanted them just to be able to save PDFs on their C drive, but Windows 10 makes this difficult to do, hence why I wanted the PDFs to open automatically and avoid this problem of needing the priveledge to save documents to other people's C drives...

Comment: You should never put files in directly in the C drive. Use the user document folder or the windows temp folder. they are made for that. You can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` as the current user `MyDocument` folder. You can also use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` for the temp folder

Comment: Thanks Franck. I didn't actually realise that if I just delete the "C:/Users/bra/" in the code above then it will save the '800C.pdf' file onto my computer or another user's computer without any problems. This solves my original problem. My new problem is that it's not very easy to find the file location afterwards, (you have to search for it). Is it possible to modify the code so that it can automatically output the file location? I tried to use the 'Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments' code  but couldn't find a way to get it to save the file to the My Documents folder on the C drive.

Comment: namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document document = new Document();

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("800C.pdf", FileMode.Create));

            document.Open();

            document.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Use formulations.");
            document.Add(p1);

            document.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

Comment: For example, could the code line above where it reads: Console.WriteLine(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); be modified so that the code within the brackets gives the location where the document has been saved on the C drive automatically? (By seaching for the document I can see that it has been saved here: C:\Users\bra\source\repos\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Debug)

Comment: if you do not specify a folder path the path is considered to be your startup path so it automatically concatenate your path to where your exe is running in front of the filename. That path is also an accessible path with `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I needed!